# If $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous at $x_0$, need it follow that $f_n(x_n) \rightarrow f_n(x_0)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a real sequence of functions defined on some subset $E$ of $\mathbb R$.

Need it be that: if $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous at $x_0 \in E$, then $f_n(x_n) - f_n(x_0)$ converges to $0$ for any $(x_n)$ converging to $x_0$?

Please provide a link to a proof, or a proof sketch in case it holds.

Comment: You're letting $n$ go to infinity in $x_{n}$ but not in $f_{n}$!

Comment: Additional question: can you provide a counterexample for a sequence which is not equicontinuous? Should be easy considering your other posts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$,

1. There exits $\delta>0$ such that $|x-x_0| < \varepsilon$ implies that $u_n(x) =|f_n(x) - f_n(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ for all values of $n$.
2. There exists $N$ such that $|x_n - x_0| < \delta$ for all values of $n$ such that $n>N$.

Whenever $n>N$, $u_n(x_n) < \varepsilon$. Thus $u_n(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, which is same as saying that $f_n(x_n) - f(x_0) \rightarrow 0$.